# Subtract 1 month strange behavior at last day of the month

Tags: javascript, date

```js
marchDay30 = new Date(2020, 2, 30);
marchDay29 = new Date(2020, 2, 29);
subtractOneMonth = (date) => new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1))
idLikeToBeFebruaryButAmNot = subtractOneMonth(marchDay30)
IAmFebruaryOk = subtractOneMonth(marchDay29)
console.log({ idLikeToBeFebruaryButAmNot, IAmFebruaryOk })
```

```
d = new Date(2020, 2, 30);
new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1)) //should be february, not march
```

Do this behaviour have a proper explanation? Any suggestion on how to build a better "get previous month (disregarding days)" function? I appreciate in advance. It works as expected if day is 29th or lower.

Comment: March 30 minus one month would be February 30 which doesnt exist

Comment: We seem to be getting lots of this question today.

Comment: I am sorry: it is beautifully answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976513/javascript-setmonth-shows-improper-date/23976655