# Problem while modifying a date (modification is wrong)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I'm trying to make a calendar in Angular. For this I have implement a drag & drop functionnality to be able to move one appointment from a day to another one.

But I have something strange, when I try to move an appointment it seems working, but when I try to move it from the 1st april to the 31 march then the date is modified to the 1st march.

When I drop my appointment I emit a change with my appointment data and the new day:

```
drop(evt) {
    let schedule: Schedule;
    schedule = evt.data.schedule;

    // Emit change
    this.scheduleChange.emit({schedule, day: this.day});
  }
```

Then I edit my appointment:

```
  scheduleChanged(evt) {
    const schedule = this.createScheduleFromObject(evt.schedule);
    const day = evt.day;

    console.log(day);

    if (this.isSameDate(schedule.start, schedule.end)) {
      schedule.start.setDate(day.getDate());
      schedule.start.setMonth(day.getMonth())
      schedule.start.setFullYear(day.getFullYear());

      schedule.end.setDate(day.getDate());
      schedule.end.setMonth(day.getMonth());
      schedule.end.setFullYear(day.getFullYear());
      console.log(schedule);
    }
  }
```

I think the problem is when I transform my object to a Schedule class:

```
 createScheduleFromObject(obj: any) {
    const schedule: Schedule = Object.assign(new Schedule(null, '', '', '', new Date(), new Date()), obj);
    console.log(obj.start);
    schedule.start = new Date(obj.start);
    schedule.end = new Date(obj.end);
    console.log(schedule.start);

    return schedule;
  }
```

This function return the good date here is the output of the console log:

```
2020-04-01T21:31:49.640Z
Wed Apr 01 2020 23:31:49 GMT+0200
```

But when I modify it in the `scheduleChanged` function even if the day is the 31st march as I have in the console log:

```
Tue Mar 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

The start date of my schedule is set to :

```
Sun Mar 01 2020 23:33:19 GMT+0100
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a duplicate of [Javascript setMonth shows improper date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976513/javascript-setmonth-shows-improper-date). What is likely happening in your case is that moving a date for April to 31 March, you are setting the day in April to a non–existent date, so it rolls over to the next month.

When setting the values of a date one at a time, you may have issues where the date of the starting Date doesn't exist in the month being set. So when setting the values of a date to new values, do it all in one go, so instead of:

```
  schedule.start.setDate(day.getDate());
  schedule.start.setMonth(day.getMonth())
  schedule.start.setFullYear(day.getFullYear());
```

do:

```
  schedule.start.setFullYear(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDate());
```

So in your case, moving a date from 1 April to 31 March:

1. The April date is set to 31, which doesn't exist so rolls over to 1 May
2. The month is set to March
3. Year is set to whatever

So you end up with a Date for 1 March. Setting the values in one go fixes that so:

1. (2020-04-01).setFullYear(2020, 2, 31) -> 2020-03-31

When setting the year, you can also set the month and day, when setting month you can set the month and day. Similarly for time, setting hours can set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Setting minutes can set minutes, seconds and milliseconds, etc.

Comment: Thanks that was that!